# ASUSTeK - Can not understand PSU sensors

Tags: ipmi, asus

I'm currently checking an ASUS server with the KMPA-U16 Series motherboard and RS500A-E11-RS12U case. I'm having trouble determining whether the PSU is working properly or not.

Dashboard -> PSU Cold Redundancy -> Cold Redundancy inactive on both PSUs. It is enabled in settings.

Sensor tab -> Both PSUs have the same state.
PSU2 PWR Detect -> Presence detected.

I see 280W on PSU1 and 10W on PSU2 (I have cold redundancy enabled) - I would disable it, but I do not want to touch it at the moment as I cannot power off the server.

System Inventory -> Power -> PSU 2 status -> VOUT_Warning/Fault POWER_GOOD_Negated Unit_is_off.

It seems like both these sensors are reporting opposite states. Can you please confirm if PSU 2 is faulty and whether the loss of power to PSU1 will cause the server to power off?

Comment: we cant know, open plese a ticket on the vendor - sometimes it helps to re-plug the entire PSU